# Python numpy - Giving identity matrix with non-diognal elements non-zero

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, mat

I'm using python numpy for matrix operations. Calculation of identity matrix is giving unexpected results - Not getting the standard identity matrix.

```
R0 = matrix([
    [0.02187598,  0.98329681, -0.18068986],
    [0.99856708, -0.01266115,  0.05199501],
    [0.04883878, -0.18156839, -0.9821648]
]);

print R0.dot(R0.I) 

# prints [[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  5.55111512e-17]
#         [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
#         [ -5.55111512e-17   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using NumPy arrays instead of the matrix types?

Comment: Because I googled, and these are the ones I found first. If numpy arrays give correct result, I can use those. Not a problem.

Comment: Using a numpy array instead of a `matrix` will not help.  You are seeing normal floating point numerical error.  In general, the result of numerically computing `R0.dot(R0.I)` will not be *exactly* the identity matrix.

Comment: This normal numerical error can cause problem, as it will result in rotating the object when the object shouldn't move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even though mathematically the result of dot(R, R.I) is equal to I, due to numerical errors in the floating point numbers, numpy returns something very close to I, but not exactly equal to it.

The values with e-17 are very close approximations of 0.

If you want to generate the exact identity matrix, just use numpy.identity:

> numpy.identity(3)